# How to add a customize buttons in dojox grid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I've developed web applications with Dojo for more than one year, and I've used dojox grid a lot, but there is no way to add customize buttons on DataGrid or EnhancedGrid, as I know that ExtJS, or EasyUI, jQuery jqgrid are capable doing this.

So I want to ask if there is any way that can add buttons or other HTML DOM in the `dojox.DataGrid`?

Answer (score 0):

at least, you can add `dojo.form.Button`'s to it. simly add an element to the `structure`-property of your `DataGrid` like that (sorry, due to no-time i just copy pasted it from an actual project of mine...):

```
  {
    name: ' ',
    field: 'idx',
    type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
    editable: false,
    formatter: function (idx) {
      return new dijit.form.Button({
        _destroyOnRemove: true,
        label: 'Bearbeiten',
        onClick: function () {
          dojo.byId('clickedItemIdx').value = idx + '';

          if (reports.entries[idx].type == 'Rufbereitschaft') {
            dojo.byId('addOrEditEntry_OCD_btn').click();
          } else {
            dojo.byId('addOrEditEntry_ASS_btn').click();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

note that my `data` contains an `idx`-`field` which i commit to the `onclick`-function in order to know which element was clicked. This is the only way i got this to work.

As you may know, you can add multiple of those `structure`-elements referring to the same `field`.